# Basic programming. "While". How to code a loop like in C

Tags: programming

I want to make a loop with While like in C language

My code is like this, but I don't know how to make all actions before the recursion. I put "&" , "And" , commas at the final of all lines but nothing worked, and the help doesn't have a case like this.

---

```
While[time < 1,
 G1 = Sqrt[2/3]*F[time]
 G2 = 0
 fp = G1*fialpha + G2*fibeta 
 Inte = Inte + fp*temp 
 w1 = Ki*Inte + Kp*fp 
 teta = teta + w1*temp 
 fialpha = Cos[teta] 
 fibeta = Sin[teta] 
 Append[VetTen, fp] 
 Append[VetTemp, time];
time = time + temp + 0.001]
```

---

Comment: `?While` should give you useful info

Comment: @ChrisK I want to make a loop with many actions. The help just have a basic examples 
"n = 1; While[n < 4, Print[n]; n++]". 
Instead of having only Print[n] I want to do more actions there.

Comment: Use `;` to delimit your multiple actions. See `CompoundExpression[]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic loop syntax (While, Loop, Do) is very standard and with an understanding of basic procedural programming concepts they should be easy to use. Please carefully review the [looping constructs documentation page](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/LoopingConstructs.html). For now I would recommend placing semi-colons after each line in the body of your loop, i.e.

```
While[time < 1,
 G1 = Sqrt[2/3]*F[time];
 G2 = 0;
 fp = G1*fialpha + G2*fibeta ;
 Inte = Inte + fp*temp ;
 w1 = Ki*Inte + Kp*fp ;
 teta = teta + w1*temp ;
 fialpha = Cos[teta] ;
 fibeta = Sin[teta] ;
 Append[VetTen, fp] ;
 Append[VetTemp, time];
time = time + temp + 0.001;]
```

and your values will update properly, allowing you to to reference the values after che computation is complete.

Comment: Thank you.
I tried it at the first time, but my output was the two list "VetTen" and "Vettemp" but it wasn't adding the values to the list. Now I fix it. I was stupid.
Thank you. :-)